# Reading Csv File with Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a problem when I read a csv file from javascript with d3 Library.
The problem is that:

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

this is the code that I execute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
d3.csv("file:///C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Nuova/food.csv", function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Browsers enforce permissions to prevent reading files out of the local file system. To host the page instead, I'd recommend using Python's built-in server. See the D3 docs for more details: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#using

Comment: Ok! I will try using python! thank you!

Comment: I used Python but the problem persists!

Comment: Try using a relative path name for your data file, eg `d3.csv("data/food.csv", function(data) {...` if you move your food,csv file to be be in a folder called 'data', which is in the root of the python server

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem. I didn't insert the file .csv in the root of server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to be running this on a local server

Are you running the request on a local server? You can only do http requests when you're using a server. Not, for example just opening the file in a browser.

edit: As in, you need to be running a local server. I suggest WAMP if on windows or perhaps using a IDE like webstorm from jetbrains.

This is your issue, you need to be running it on a local server.

Comment: i'm using xampp as local server. but it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure the server is actually running? I tested your code on my local server and the only error I am getting is that I don't have the file. the xmlhttp request works fine...

you may be running the server, but perhaps it's in the wrong file location? it need to be in the webroot, so probablt the /www folder. Then, you open 127.0.0.1 (or wherever your local server is located). then it should work. Try this and paste the log errors please! :D

Comment: Thank you!!! I didn't insert the file .csv in the root of local server! Now I solved my problem!

Comment: Excellent! That feeling of success is great. If I answered your question, would you mind marking as answered? :)